# Is an Android app which uses local JSON files to store data vulnerable?

Tags: java, android, json, security, code-injection

My Android app uses plain text JSON files to store some data. Such files are saved into the private folder of the app, e.g. Android/data/com.example.app/. I would like to know if my app is vulnerable with such kind of files around. Data in those files are not sensible or secret, and they are not processed by JavaScript (they are parsed with JSON Java methods); I am concerned about some malicious JSON code to be injected and mess with my app or the user's device. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, data that you store into the private folder is neither accessible by the user nor by other applications. See the documentation on the Android developers website about this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

However, as mentioned by SMR, if a device has been rooted this data is available to the user and might be compromised by any apps that the user has given root permission to. 
However it's a minority of users that are actually rooted and those that are should more or less know what they've gotten themselves into and what they're actions can do. It's up to you to decide if it's worth some effort to look out for these special cases.

But by default your data should be safe and sound.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the injected code was not malicious it can cause you problems because:

- Others can see and alter the file. *(At least with rooted devices)*
- if the content is altered then you are prone have unexpected results while parsing the file.
- You would not want your app related data to be altered by others by any means unless you want it to be (but by using Content Providers.)

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: But if you dont find any alternative you can surely use some sensible signature which will always let your application identify the authenticated JSON files and differentiate them from the ones that are malicious.... does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not that much private then you can put those data in the assets folder and you can access the same. If it is not like that then you can keep it inside the applications data folder